# How To download and caching bitmap using Picasso library

Tags: android, image, picasso

I am using the following method

```
Bitmap bitmap = Picasso.with(ListofCardsActivity.this)
                            .load(overLayUrl).get();
```

for downloading and get the image from the web url.

Does this method download the image from the url every time, even if it is downloaded already?

What I want is that once the image is downloaded, then from the next time onwards, I should get the image from the cache, no need to download.

If we have the method like the above requirement. please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this method download the image from the url every time, even if it is downloaded already?

Not if it is cached.

The [`Picasso` instance you get back with `with()`](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#with%28android.content.Context%29) is pre-configured to have a memory cache and a disk cache.

Depending on how much you are downloading, you may run out of cache space. And I would hope that Picasso uses stuff like `ETag` and `If-Modified-Since` to re-download the image if the image has changed on the server, though I have not examined their code to see if they do, as that behavior is not documented.

Comment: Thank you .. by seeing their code and comment for that method i believe that they are not chaching , and they are downloading every time. and my app is also takes time for every time display. can you please provide me the link of any library which supports for the same requirement... @CommonsWare

Comment: @AndroidDev: "by seeing their code and comment for that method i believe that they are not chaching , and they are downloading every time" -- you are welcome to believe whatever you want. The JavaDocs state that they have enabled caching, and [the source code to the `Picasso` class](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.java) shows where they have configured an `LruCache` by default.

Comment: SO that means they are not downloading the image every time right? @CommonsWare

Comment: @AndroidDev: They should not be downloading images that are already cached. They *may* be doing conditional `HTTP GET` requests, using `ETag` and/or `If-Modified-Since`, to see if the cache has an up-to-date copy of the image -- I have not researched this point.

Comment: Picasso doesn't do any explicit disk caching. That's handled 100% by the HTTP client. We do configure the disk cache in the client (if you haven't already) as you said. Normal HTTP cache semantics apply and things like `ETag`, conditional `GET`s, etc. apply, also as you said in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this method download the image from the url every time, even if it is downloaded already?
>   Not if it is cached.

According to the documentation and the source code, Picasso doesn't cache anything when using synchronous **get()** method.

So here is my solution for loading image synchronously and caching it with Picasso:

```
    File fileImage = new File("/path/to/your/image");

    final Bitmap[] bmpRes = new Bitmap[1];
    final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    Picasso.with(this).load(fileImage).priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH).into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            bmpRes[0] = bitmap;
            semaphore.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            semaphore.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    });
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(bmpRes[0] != null) {
        Bitmap bmp = bmpRes[0];
        //TODO: Whatever you want with the bitmap
    } else {
        //TODO: Failed to load the image
    }
```